# Deployment Targets for my app

Tags: ios, ios7

I am planning to launch my app soon and it should support iOS 7+

Based on this, should my iOS deployment target setting and deployment target be for 7.0? 
Also why are there two settings available (one is for the project itself, one is for the target).

Does the project setting simply mean what functionality (function names, APIs, etc) are available to me and the deployment target simply mean what is the minimum version i'd like people to be able to use my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have more than one Target in your Project. so Target Settings will apply for particular Target, you can have different settings for each target when you have more than one.

Project settings means it will apply for all the Targets.

You might see some of the settings in both Target and Project, if you have set to default/not mentioned in Target it will take the setting project.

Comment: So if I leave it as 8.1 and don't add anything else, that means people < 8.1 won't be able to use it?

Comment: thanks, and if I do 7 it would be 7 only and not 8 right? So the idea is I want multiple?